# xaml editor shows messy hint in vs 2017

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

As the picture shows, my xaml editor shows messy hint, I can't read the words......

Does anyone has the same problem?

Win10 16299

Vs2017 15.5.1(In fact, it exists for a long time, including the older vs versions)

Comment: Looks like you installed vs in language other than English , if you paste that line of error , so we can translate it, or wait if any one knows that language may reply. Or if you are installed eng version of vs you should check in settings and look into fonts may be deleted or unlocated

Comment: Hi, I installed Chinese version only, but the hint is not Chinese words. The errors are like ￦ﾜﾪ￨ﾃﾽ￦ﾉﾾ￥ﾈﾰ￥ﾱﾞ￦ﾀﾧ￢ﾀﾜ￢ﾀﾝ ﾀﾂ

Comment: okay you are right i translate this words no meaning found. so can you paste that xaml codes which gives you this error, so i can test in my copy of vs2017

Comment: The code is fine and compile fine.                             <ToggleSwitch x:Uid="Settings_Theme" Header="Theme" IsOn="{x:Bind IsLightThemeEnabled, Mode=OneWay}" Toggled="ThemeToggle_Toggled"/>  After I add  Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="Default" , it shows the hint. But this is normal, only the xaml editor can't recognize immediately and shows messy words.

Comment: What is the target min version of the project? It is possible this is the min. version warning that you are seeing i.e. the type you are using is not compatible with the min. version of the project.

Comment: Maybe. This occurs a long time, and the vs team even have not notice it. The latest vs version still the same.